# What causes the Fermi Tail in Photoelectric effect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, photoelectric-effect

I did a Photoelectric effect experiment, with this setup (schematic):
[image]
**Figure 1 Scheme of the setup**
The kathode is made of Potassium. Light is passing through the monochromator and on the kathode. Which releases electrons out of the kathode. In this experiment, I tried to find the voltage that is needed to stop the electrons from moving, in other words; change the voltage until there is not current.

The current was measured by a Keithly Electrometer and resulted into this:
[image]

**Figure 2 Measurements with different wave lenghts**
You would expect that it would be lineair. But as you can see, it isn't.
This effect is called the "Fermi Tail". But why is there a so called fermi tail? What is causing this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we think of the Fermi tail as being due to electrons that are thermally excited into states that are above the Fermi energy.  This has the effect of slightly reducing the work function.  There aren't too many electrons promoted in such a way, so the tail is evident only at low voltages w.r.t. the work function.  Hence: a tail.  I would expect this effect to cause a tail of about 25 mV.  Your graphs suggest that the tail is 100 mV, so there may be something else going on, perhaps involving impurities, or perhaps surface irregularities which might enhance the electric field locally.  Or perhaps I'm just being too strict in the interpretation of the data.

Comment: So, just for clearity. That 'tail' appears, because of the thermal energy of the electrons, the work function will reduce for some electrons. And because there are just a few electrons with that lower work function, is it only visible with lower currents. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Can you explain to me how and why surface irregularities can make that tail 'longer' to about 100 mV?

Comment: First:  I'm not at all sure that what I suggested actually occurs.  However, it is known that electric fields are enhanced in the vicinity of sharp points.  What works for lightning rods, also works microscopically.  So an electric field can be locally greater than the applied field.